# How can I improve my model's prediction based on test set accuracy socres?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, polynomial

Perhaps that's a bad way to phrase this question, but I'm much more of a coder than a statistician. I would really appreciate help on the following:

This pretty picture shows three predictions by my model, with respective accuracies of 50%, 52% and 55%.

We can spot a fairly clear trend here and I while I believe this shows that there's plenty of room for optimization, I'm also wondering, what kinds of transformations can be carried out using information drawn from the respective accuracy differences and the prediction values?

I've split up the four large clusters (with k-Means), gathered min, max, mean, std-dev and variance for each of them, and made some simple regression plots. I would now like to fit a polynomial regression, but I am unsure how to parametrize my model such that it describes this trend of convergence that I'm noticing.

I'm exploring the value of this type of retrospective analysis and I would really appreciate some insight.

[image]

Comment: What is `id`, what is `y`, and what is the color? // Red/greed colorblindness is not uncommon, and it not the best practice to mix those colors in a figure.

Comment: @Dave thank you Dave- I'll be sure to keep that in mind. ID is the prediction index (each ID corresponds to a row in the dataset containing the features the model is based on), y is the prediction score, given the features at ID. The color is according to the model's parameter settings, not relevant.